# how to plot a 3-column file .txt in R?

Tags: r

I've got a 3-column .txt file where the first column is a contiguous integer index and the other 2 columns are floating-point values.

The task is to plot in x the first column and in y the remaining two columns

Sounds very simple but isn't actually very obvious to do for me because I'm very new to R, so excuse me for a question probably stupid.

Comment: so you want one y-axis on the left and one y-axis on the right?
which function do you use? plot? ggplot2?

there some nice solutions on stackoverflow like
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes

Comment: I would like to see in the same x-y plot the data took from my .txt file. the first column of the file would be my x and the remaining two column are the y. I was trying to use plot

Comment: Please add reproducibility to your question. Most possible ways to do it have been [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `library(lattice)
data = c()
head(s)
data = data.frame("Mutual_information.txt", header = T, sep = ",")
plot(1, 2, ylab="Mutual Information")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(1, 3, axes = F, ylab="Mutual Information", type="l")`

Answer (score 0):

try this very basic example

```
x <- c(1:4)
y1 <- c(5:8)
y2 <- c(1,8,12,14)
df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y2,type="l",col="blue")
axis(4)
```

Comment: I have tried this:

data = data.frame("Mutual_information.txt", header = T, sep = ",")
plot(1, 2, ylab="Mutual Information")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(1, 3, axes = F, ylab="Mutual Information", type="l")

the problem is that what I've called 1,2 and 1,3  might be my file's column...they don't have a name so I don't know how to put them in my plot...sorry for the silly questions XD

Comment: @laura try my example step by step. did you try to add `par(new=TRUE)` between your plots?

Comment: yes I've tried your example and it is exactly what I have to do..and what I did...my problem now is to put the first column of my file in x and the other two columns in y. In my file the 3columns are not named they are just numbers so I don't know how to do that. thank you very much