# Displaying multiple variables on one plot in R

Tags: r

I have clinical data with:

```
Type, Age, Sex
One, 24, M
Two, 45, F
One, 48, M
.
.
.
```

I would like to use R to show some useful plots, for example a box plot.

I would like to have `Type` on the x-axis and `Age` on the y-axis with vertical boxes, but also split by `Sex`, so separate for male and female but grouped by `Type`.

My first try is:

```
DATA_SET <- read.csv("myfile.csv")
x <- DATA_SET[,'Type']
y <- DATA_SET[,'Age']
plot(x,y)
```

It's quite okay but I would like to add titles to each axis and have more values (be more acurate for readers) on the y-axis. And most importantly, split each box into two--separate for male and female.

Comment: This [link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) should serve as a starting point. Also look at the `facet_wrap` function in ggplot2.

Comment: This question is very broad, not very clear, and the title doesn't seem to match the question. It sounds like you want _separate_ plots for _one_ variable, rather than _one_ plot for _multiple_ variables.

Comment: I would like to have values fro two y sets (age) and one x set (types) on the same plot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes