# twoord plot in R

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

Using the **plotrix** package to make a twoord plot. My attempts look like this

The problem I have is that it automatically does not plot the full left axis? Why is this?

It is the same in this example here 
[How can I plot with 2 different y-axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes)

How is it possible to get the full left y?

Comment: please provide an reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't provide your data or your code, I offer this as an example:

```
library(plotrix)

twoord.plot(2:10, seq(3, 7, by=0.5) + rnorm(9),
            1:15, rev(60:74) + rnorm(15), 
            type= c("l", "l"), xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
```

[image]