# 2-y Axes Plot with calculated absolute & relative Change in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to calculate two things in R, *Relative & Absolute Change*, & plot *2-y axis scatter plots*. I am still **seeking inputs** on creating a 2-y axis plot for this type of data.

```
set.seed(123)
df=expand.grid(PatientID=1:3,time=1:3, Group=1:2)
dat <- data.table(df,Outcome=as.integer(runif(9)*100))
```

Data Format df #sample

```
PatientID time Outcome Group
     1     1    87 1
     1     2    32 1
     1     3    76 2
     2     1    21 2
     2     2    23 3
     2     3    23 3

 ## Cont until 200 PatientID or volunteers and there are many outcome measure columns (33:290)
```

PatientID, time, Outcome, Group denote volunteers' identification number, time of visiting a hospital, outcome measure of interest and Group (whether they belong to a condition A or B) respectively. Data includes 3 visits by participants and two groups.

1. **Relative Change(%)**, i.e. expresses the absolute change as a percentage of the outcome from baseline time point, for Group 1 & 2.

[(F -  B )/ B]*100, here B and F are baseline and follow up values of a outcome measure

2. **Absolute Change**, i.e. F-B
3. **2-y axes scatter plots**:

The prime purpose of this plot is to look at the changes in outcome measures with respect to baseline (time=1), and also determine if there are group differences. It is prudent to include respective relative/absolute change values in the plot as y1 and y2.

I had made several scatterplots in ggplot2 and ggvis to view the trends, but I did not find a direct option to calculate (& plot) relative & absolute change through the ggplot2 & ggvis packages. I really recommend using them for novice users, like myself. In addition, I am also planning to incorporate relative & absolute change values in one scatterplot itself for one outcome measure, i.e. 2-y axes plots.

Let me know if you require some more clarifications. Thanks, and looking forward!

**Answers for 1 & 2 Ques** #thought it might help others

This is how I finally did it:

`library(dplyr)
dft1= filter(df, df$time==1)
dft2= filter(df, df$time==2)
dft3= filter(df, df$time==3)`

To calculate absolute change from second to first time point & third to first time point: 
`abs1=dft2[33:290] - dft1[33:290]`

`abs2=dft3[33:290] - dft1[33:290]`

To calculate relative change from second to first time point & third to first time point: 
`rel1=abs1/dft1[33:290]*100`

`rel2=abs2/dft1[33:290]*100`

I will put absolute change and relative change on different y-axis axes. This link was handy to get me started: ([How can I plot with 2 different y-axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes)).

Nice resource for learning R: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: You know about precedence of operations? I.e. first `/` or `*` and then `+` or `-`.

Comment: You know your data.table example line does absolutely not produce your example data.frame ?

Comment: @Tensibai: Nope, looks like I need to improvise it so that people can understand what I am asking

Comment: Thanks, Tensibai. I get an error with the code you gave. "Error in data.table(df, Outcome = as.integer(runif(9) * 100)) : 
  problem recycling column 1, try a simpler type"

Comment: Aww, sorry, forgot a line :p `set.seed(123);df=expand.grid(PatientID=1:3,time=1:3);dat <- data.table(df,Outcome=as.integer(runif(9)*100))`

Comment: It is alright. New code for creating data table works, thanks again for your time. There are different values in outcome measures, but that does not matter much.

Comment: @Dr.AmitBansal think about editing your question to improve it :)

Comment: You could improve your question by showing the effort you invested and where you get stuck. Right now I read it as an analysis request, which I would deem less suitable for stackoverflow but rather something a hired gun would do.

Comment: @Tensibai - I have made a few changes :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - You got me wrong. I have data with analysis done, but I wanna learn R and reciprocate graphs (similar to what people in my field make), so asking a few questions on where I got stuck. I hope the edited question clarifies most concerns. If not, pls feel free to shot again!

Answer (score 3):

Not clear exactly what you mean but you should be able to modify this code to achieve your purpose:

```
dat = data.table(PatientID=c(1,2), time=c(1:3), Outcome=c(87, 32,76,21,24, 27))
#Modified so you can actually compare across 2 time periods
#Note your data is already sorted, but to be on the safe side:
setkey(dat,PatientID,time)
dat[, `:=`(rel.change.1 = 100 * (Outcome - shift(Outcome)) / Outcome,
           rel.change.2 = 100 * (Outcome - shift(Outcome, 2)) / Outcome,
           abs.change.1 = Outcome - shift(Outcome),
           abs.change.2 = Outcome - shift(Outcome, 2)),
           by = PatientID]
```

The key idea is to use `shift` to get a shift of the `Outcome` column; the second argument to shift is the number of rows by which to shift it. Combined with grouping by `PatientID`, and given that we keyed the `data.table` in order to ensure it was sorted by `time` within groups of `PatientID`, this ensures the correct comparison. (Note, if your actual data is not complete, this will not produce correct results. For example, if you have observations at times 1 and 4 for PatientID=1 but 2 and 3 for PatientID = 2, then both 1-shifts will compare these observations even though they are not the same number of time units apart. If this is the case you should use `CJ` on the ID and time columns to get rows in which you fill `NAs` for all the missing observations; that will ensure that the shifts reflect the correct time differences.)

This produces:

```
> dat
   PatientID time Outcome rel.change.1 rel.change.2 abs.change.1 abs.change.2
1:         1    1      87           NA           NA           NA           NA
2:         1    2      24   -262.50000           NA          -63           NA
3:         1    3      76     68.42105    -14.47368           52          -11
4:         2    1      21           NA           NA           NA           NA
5:         2    2      32     34.37500           NA           11           NA
6:         2    3      27    -18.51852     22.22222           -5            6
```

Now, we can melt,

```
melted <- melt(dat,id.vars=c("PatientID","time"),variable.factor=F)

> melted
    PatientID time     variable      value
 1:         1    1      Outcome   87.00000
 2:         1    2      Outcome   24.00000
 3:         1    3      Outcome   76.00000
 4:         2    1      Outcome   21.00000
 5:         2    2      Outcome   32.00000
 6:         2    3      Outcome   27.00000
 7:         1    1 rel.change.1         NA
 8:         1    2 rel.change.1 -262.50000
 9:         1    3 rel.change.1   68.42105
10:         2    1 rel.change.1         NA
11:         2    2 rel.change.1   34.37500
12:         2    3 rel.change.1  -18.51852
13:         1    1 rel.change.2         NA
14:         1    2 rel.change.2         NA
15:         1    3 rel.change.2  -14.47368
16:         2    1 rel.change.2         NA
17:         2    2 rel.change.2         NA
18:         2    3 rel.change.2   22.22222
19:         1    1 abs.change.1         NA
20:         1    2 abs.change.1  -63.00000
21:         1    3 abs.change.1   52.00000
22:         2    1 abs.change.1         NA
23:         2    2 abs.change.1   11.00000
24:         2    3 abs.change.1   -5.00000
25:         1    1 abs.change.2         NA
26:         1    2 abs.change.2         NA
27:         1    3 abs.change.2  -11.00000
28:         2    1 abs.change.2         NA
29:         2    2 abs.change.2         NA
30:         2    3 abs.change.2    6.00000
    PatientID time     variable      value
```

And plot

```
ggplot(melted,aes(x=time,y=value,color=factor(PatientID))) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free") +
    labs(color="PatientID")
```

[image: Example plot of raw data and all computed variables in facets]

Comment: If your grouping variable is always `PatientID`, why are you running this 4 times? Can't you just create them all in a single run?

Comment: Good point, and in fact you could even functionalize the operation to create abs/rel change in terms of `n` and `lapply` to create the shifts for each `n` in `1:n`. But as this is a toy example for a novice user who stated he had a total of 200 obs groups (negating any need for speed), and who may run line-by-line in a REPL to learn what each line does, I think OP may have an easier time following this syntax than a one-liner like `dat[,c("...","...","...","..."):=.(...,...,...,...),by=...]` (let alone something like `lapply(1:2,function(n) dat[,c("..",".."):=.(eval(parse(text=...)),...)`).

Comment: That said, please feel free to edit my post to add the example of doing this with only one pass.

Comment: Many thanks, Philip. Adding PatientID, in color aesthetics, might make it hard to understand the data as there are hundreds of participants, and I am basically looking at overall changes in outcome measure with respect to baseline time point (not individual changes). I have a separate column for grouping variable, "Group". I will also compare two groups, but I have not mentioned that in the main question. Thank again for taking your time.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean for you literally to use the graph example I posted, just to get a sense of what's out there. Check out `stat_summary`, in particular given that you have groups you will probably want to `group` or `color` by `Group` and a `stat_summary` can average (or whatever you want) over all the observations in that group. (BTW, I understand now that you meant all your comparisons to be to time-1 rather than at fixed intervals of time of given lengths, but didn't realize this before, so I see that my answer isn't quite applicable to your case.)

Comment: @DavidArenburg - It is a good alternative, thanks. As @Philip guessed, it's easier for me to run `codes` line-by-line and I prefer to understand my script/code, but I also need to learn more about loops and lapply. So any suggestion, or a brief code to play with, is welcome! Learning by trying :)

Answer (score 2):

Other approach:

```
set.seed(123)
df = expand.grid(PatientID = 1:3,time = 1:3)
dat <- data.table(df,Outcome = as.integer(runif(9) * 100))

setkeyv(dat,"PatientID")
dat[, abs.change := (Outcome - Outcome[time == 1]), by = PatientID]
dat[, rel.change := abs.change / Outcome[time == 1], by = PatientID]

ggplot(melt(dat,c('PatientID','time')), aes(x = time,y = value,color = factor(PatientID))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ variable,scales = "free")
```

Which gives (drawing borrowed from @Philip answer):

[image]

You can chain the two steps of adding columns like this (but it's less readable):

```
dat[, abs.change := (Outcome - Outcome[time == 1]), by = PatientID][, rel.change := abs.change / Outcome[time == 1], by = PatientID]
```

Comment: Thanks, Tensibai. I am again getting error message with "setkey(dat,"PatientID")". Error message - "Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) :  x is not a data.table". Any thoughts? Nice plots, how do I put relative change (percentage) & absolute change values in the graphs? Abuse legend option or  is there a legit way to do this?

Comment: Try a `setDT(dat)` for your real data, (which sounds to be a data.frame then). I don't get your question about the plots, there's 3 plots, one for each "variable", I assume this become a different question.

Comment: The syntax is either `setkey(dat,PatientID)` or `setkeyv(dat,"PatientID")`. Use `v` when the argument is a character string. Make sure that `dat` actually *is* a `data.table` (check with `class(dat)`).

Comment: @Philip good catch, my session didn't complain about it, fixing the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks. I changed `dat` from a data.frame to data.table. After running `dat[, abs.change := (Outcome - Outcome[time == 1]), by = PatientID]`, I received an error: "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)". Then, I ran ggplot command, I got another error: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? Warning message: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped". Still checking alternatives. Thanks again!