# Subtract one row from another row in df

Tags: r

I have DF which looks like

```
DF
Nrow  a   b    c   d
1     0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
2      2   3   4   5
3      7   8   9   10
```

I want to subtract row 1 from row 2 and row 3.

How can i do it ?
Thank you for any tips.

**Updates**

I saw this code: [within-group differences from group member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781173/within-group-differences-from-group-member), and tried it as well.

Edited my data:

`newdf <- df[!is.na(S[,1]),]` ## df had NA values which was interfering with analysis, so I removed them.

`df <- data.frame(treatment = rep(c('','baseline', 'treatment 1', 'treatment 2'), times=372),S[c(1:258)])`

`A <- df %>%
  mutate_each(funs(. - .[treatment=="baseline"]), -treatment) %>%
  filter(treatment!="baseline")`  ##have multiple columns for which I would like to calculate row-wise change

`View(A)`

However, now I thought to get correct results (or absolute change, i.e.  row 2 - row 1), but the values are different from what I can calculate manually. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**Answers 11.03.2016**

[2-y Axes Plot with calculated absolute & relative Change in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741538/2-y-axes-plot-with-absolute-relative-change-in-r-with-answers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781173/within-group-differences-from-group-member

Comment: Don't add resolved to the title, accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 11.03.2016** #thought it might help others

This is how I finally did it:

`library(dplyr)
dft1= filter(df, df$time==1)
dft2= filter(df, df$time==2)
dft3= filter(df, df$time==3)`

You might need to rename data frame or columns in accordance to your data set.

To calculate absolute change from second to first time point & third to first time point: 
`abs1=dft2[33:290] - dft1[33:290]`

`abs2=dft3[33:290] - dft1[33:290]`

To calculate relative change from second to first time point & third to first time point: 
`rel1=abs1/dft1[33:290]*100`

`rel2=abs2/dft1[33:290]*100`

Answer (score 2):

If we need to subtract a single row from multiple rows, we can `rep` the the single row to make the dimension as that of the subset of dataset with multiple rows and then do the subtraction.

```
DF[2:3, -1]- DF[rep(1,2),-1]
#   a   b   c   d
#2 1.9 2.8 3.7 4.6
#3 6.9 7.8 8.7 9.6
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Nrow = 1:3, a = c(0.1, 2, 7), b = c(0.2, 3, 8), 
c = c(0.3, 4, 9), d = c(0.4, 5, 10)), .Names = c("Nrow", 
"a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. What if some of those values are NA? How can I omit them to calculate difference? Also, I am getting a `warning messages: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @Dr.AmitBansal  When you post a dataset with numeric values and the question is to subtract between rows, we expect it to be `numeric` class.  For some reason, your columns are `factor`.  You can convert it to numeric as mentioned by cory in the comments.  If there are NA values, you can replace those with 0 (if that makes sense) i.e. `DF1 <- replace(DF1, is.na(DF1), 0)` (after converting the columns to `numeric`).

Answer (score 0):

Use indexes to look at rows...

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("Nrow  a   b    c   d
1     0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
2      2   3   4   5
3      7   8   9   10"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

df[1, ] - df[2, ]
# or assign the result to a new row...
df <- rbind(df, df[1, ] - df[2, ])
```

Comment: Thank you, @cory! What if some of those values are NA? How can I omit them to calculate difference? Also, I am getting a `warning messages: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: Some of your columns are factors. If these are supposed to be numeric values, then you'll need to do a `as.numeric(as.character(your factor var))`

Answer (score 0):

The following commands would perform the subtraction of 1st row from all the rows below, and will print the result of subtraction of 1st row from rows below.

```
 data = data.frame(x=c(1,5,7,10),y=c(3,2,4,1.1),z=1:4)
 data
 #    x    y  z
 # 1  1  3.0  1
 # 2  5  2.0  2
 # 3  7  4.0  3
 # 4 10  1.1  4

 for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
 result = data[i,] - data[1,]
 print (result)
 }

 #     x   y  z    
 # 2   4  -1  1     <--- 2nd row minus 1st row

 #     x   y  z
 # 3   6   1  2     <--- 3rd row minus 1st row

 #     x   y  z
 # 4   9 -1.9 3     <--- 4th row minus 1st row
```

Hope this helped. You can use the same commands for any number of rows in your data.