# Abline clip for secondary axis

Tags: r, line, yaxis

With the `ablineclip` I can draw a straight line to any plot like:

```
 ablineclip(h = 2, x1 = 0,x2 = 5,lty = 2, col = "green")
```

this draws a horizontal line where y=2 from x=0 to x=5.

How can I draw a line for a second y axis??
(meaning a horizontal line where y value on the right axis is 2).

I have no code yet, sorry for the non reproductive code.

Comment: Which packages did you load? `ablineclip` is not included in the base package.

Comment: What have you searched / tried ? (Just to avoid suggesting the same things)

Comment: I am sorry, package 'plotrix'.  @Llopis,  I found only the 'triax.abline' which displays lines for triangle plots.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-single-plot-with-two-different-y-axes/) Or this other question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes this might help you if I understood correctly

Comment: @Llopis thank you for the links, but I already have a plot with 2axis and I want to draw a horizontal line where y on the right axis is 2. This is an example with a single y axis and the 'abline'. https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/ablineclip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following will work:

```
library(plotrix)
plot(1, type="n", xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(0,4))
ablineclip(h = 2, x1 = 0,x2 = 5,lty = 2, col = "green")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(1, type="n", xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(10,15), xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
ablineclip(h = 12, x1 = -4,x2 = 4,lty = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With the 'par' works! Just wondering, is it possible to use the abline for the same thing with twoord plots?