# how to plot data on top of each other and two axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a data set like this

```
df<- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Control1", 
"Control2", "Control3", "Control4", "Control5", "Control6", "Control7"
), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Cond1", "Cond2", "Cond3"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(1.1, 1.7, -0.7, 0.8, 1.9, -0.71, 1.6, 1.6, -0.5, 
    1.9, 1.8, -0.6, 1.7, 1.5, -0.9, 1.3, 1.5, -0.7, 1.2, 1.6, 
    -0.5), Signifcance = c(1.06e-18, 9.4e-20, 9e-04, 5.7e-10, 
    3.02e-50, 8.01e-08, 1.4e-19, 8.6e-83, 3.2e-07, 6.8e-15, 1.2e-92, 
    1.7e-09, 6.2e-15, 3.4e-68, 1.4e-09, 6.9e-15, 2.3e-48, 4.3e-12, 
    1.1e-21, 1.7e-141, 1.4e-08)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

I have been trying to figure out how to plot the data on top of each other based on the first column

If you look at the column X, there are Control1 (3 times) Control2(3 times) etc. In each control I have 3 conditions 
I wanted to have 3 lines corresponding to each cond across all Controls versus one axis and then one line for the significanc value for each with another color.

I checked here and I found this solution but I cannot figure out how to use it for this data 
[How can I plot with 2 different y-axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes#)

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you want the resulting plot to look like, but is this going in the direction you intended?

```
mat = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4), 3, 2, byrow = F)
layout(mat)

plot(df[df$name == "Cond1",]$Value, col="red", type="l", ylim=c(min(df$Value), max(df$Value)), ylab="Value", main="Values")
lines(df[df$name == "Cond2",]$Value, col="blue", type="l")
lines(df[df$name == "Cond3",]$Value, col="green", type="l")
legend("right", legend = c("Cond1","Cond2","Cond3"), lwd = c(1,1,1), col=c("red","blue","green"))


plot(df[df$name == "Cond1",]$Signifcance, col="red", lty=2, type="l", ylab="Sign.", main="Significance")
plot(df[df$name == "Cond2",]$Signifcance, col="blue", lty=2, type="l",ylab="Sign.")
plot(df[df$name == "Cond3",]$Signifcance, col="green", lty=2, type="l",ylab="Sign.")
legend("right", legend = c("Cond1","Cond2","Cond3"), lty = 2, col=c("red","blue","green"))
```

---

Or with the **dev-version of ggplot2**, you can easily split the significance values in 3 plots with different y-axis.

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(X, Value, group=name, color=name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Values")

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(X, Signifcance, group=name, color=name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows=vars(name), scales = "free_y")+ 
  ggtitle("Signifcance")

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

Comment: I think you are doing the right way but I cannot understand why you plot 3 conditions and their significant on the same axis ? they are very different in magnitude , also the labeling in the x-axic does not reflact the Control .

Comment: Indeed, I just realised the same thing. Why not divide the plot, so that you have values on the left and Significance on the right? That would make the plots more readable and also easier to build?

Comment: @ SeGa is there another way that I could plot the significant so that I could show all the points or somewhat that it can be seen? also , would it be possble to add legend? and Yes definetly the second approach might be more of use :-) thanks

Comment: Just edited the answer. The plots for the significance are splitted and there is a ggplot2 version aswell.

Comment: I get this error `Error in facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales = "free_y") : 
  unused argument (rows = vars(name))`

Comment: Oh I think you need the **dev**-version of ggplot2 for that.

Comment: what is the dev-version? is there a way to get a normal one ? if no, how can I get the other one installed ?

Comment: I just added the code-snippet to install the dev (developer) version.

Comment: I accepted and liked your answer ! Thanks for your time