# ggplot2 - how to assign geom_text with arrow icon to second yaxis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 20 sets of the following dataset and would like to combine two plots into one with two y-axes that properly reflects the variable values.

```
hour=c(0:23)
conc=c(20.7, 19.4, 15.6, 11.7, 10.3, 9.1, 9.7, 10.6, 12.7, 12.6, 11, 9.8,
       9.3, 9.3, 10.3, 12.9, 17.1, 22.5, 22, 22.3, 23, 24.8, 24, 26.8)
ws=c(0.75, 0.7, 0.68, 0.64, 0.61, 0.64, 0.57, 0.58, .62, .65, .85, 1.12, 
     1.21, 1.29, 1.2, 1.18, 1.0, 0.84, .87, .75, .69, .69, .77, .74)
wd=c(295, 299, 288, 290, 292, 296, 306, 303, 300, 293, 259, 231, 94, 119, 
     95, 47, 75, 306, 302, 304, 319, 309, 290, 298)
mydf=data.frame(hour, conc, ws, wd)
```

I can plot them separately as a 1-by-2 graph using the following code:

```
conchrly <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x=hour,y=conc)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("Hour") +
  ylab("Concentration") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")     

windhrly <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x=hour, y=ws)) + 
  geom_text(aes(angle=-wd+90), label="←") +
  xlab("Hour") +
  ylab("Wind Speed") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") 

conchrly + windhrly + plot_layout(ncol=1)
```

which gives this graph:

[image: Two separate plots using plot_layout]

I'd like to combine them together as one graph with two y-axes. Most examples I found here are related to the second-axis as a duplicate or function of first y-values. My second y-variable is 'ws' which is not a function on my first y variable (ie. 'conc').

The following is my attempt to graph them together. However the y-value of second plot (geom_text which should represent my ws) are not plotted using the second y-axis.

```
ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x = hour, y = conc)) + 
  geom_line(color = "black") + 
  geom_text(data=mydf, aes(x=hour, y=ws,angle=-wd+90), label="←", colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 24, by=6), limits=c(0,24), name="Hour") + 
  scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq(0,30,10), name= "Concentration", 
     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, name = "Wind Speed (m/s)")) + 
              theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
                    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "black"))
```

[image: Combined graph with two y-axes]

How do I get those blue arrows which represent my 'ws' to be on the right scale (ie. using the second y-axis)? This is only one set and I have 19 others to do that's why I prefer to combine them into one graph per data set if possible.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This is not easily done, because these sort of dual axes are not really supported by `ggplot1`. This is because it's authors think these plots are misleading.

Comment: There are some answers using base R and some other plotting packages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can achieve what you're after if we scale values of `ws` such that they use the same range as `conc`, and then apply the inverse transformation inside `sec_axis`. The transformation that we are applying takes the form `y = a + b * x`, where `y` are the `conc` and `x` the `ws` measurements. The two scaling coefficients `a` and `b` are then obtained by solving a system of two linear equations:

```
# Calculate scaling coefficients a and b
y1 <- min(mydf$conc)
y2 <- max(mydf$conc)
x1 <- min(mydf$ws)
x2 <- max(mydf$ws)
b <- (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
a <- y1 - b * x1
```

We then calculate `ws.scaled` and apply the inverse transformation `x = (y - a) / b` inside `sec_axis`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
    mutate(ws.scaled = a + b * ws) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = conc)) +
        geom_line(color = "black") +
        geom_text(aes(x = hour, y = ws.scaled, angle = -wd + 90), label = "←", colour = "blue") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 24, by=6), limits=c(0,24), name="Hour") +
        scale_y_continuous(
            breaks = seq(0,30,10),
            name=  "Concentration",
            sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a) / b, name = "Wind Speed (m/s)")) +
            theme(
                axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
                axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "black"))
```

[image]

PS. Dual y axes are often not a good idea. Personally I prefer showing two plots.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks Maurits!

Comment: @num8ers PS. If this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant answers. Thanks and great first question btw.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks