# plot(var()) displays two different plots, how do I merge them into one? Also having two y axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series, forecast, autoregressive-models

```
> dput(head(inputData))
structure(list(Date = c("2018:07:00", "2018:06:00", "2018:05:00", 
"2018:04:00", "2018:03:00", "2018:02:00"), IIP = c(125.8, 127.5, 
129.7, 122.6, 140.3, 127.4), CPI = c(139.8, 138.5, 137.8, 137.1, 
136.5, 136.4), `Term Spread` = c(1.580025, 1.89438, 2.020112, 
1.899074, 1.470544, 1.776862), RealMoney = c(142713.9916, 140728.6495, 
140032.2762, 139845.5215, 139816.4682, 139625.865), NSE50 = c(10991.15682, 
10742.97381, 10664.44773, 10472.93333, 10232.61842, 10533.10526
), CallMoneyRate = c(6.161175, 6.10112, 5.912088, 5.902226, 5.949956, 
5.925538), STCreditSpread = c(-0.4977, -0.3619, 0.4923, 0.1592, 
0.3819, -0.1363)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to make my autoregressive plot like this plot:

[image: this plot(destination plot)]

```
#------> importing all libraries
library(readr)
install.packages("lubridtae")
library("lubridate")
install.packages("forecast")
library('ggplot2')
library('fpp')
library('forecast')
library('tseries')

#--------->reading data
inputData <- read_csv("C:/Users/sanat/Downloads/exercise_1.csv")

#--------->calculating the lag=1 for NSE50

diff_NSE50<-(diff(inputData$NSE50, lag = 1, differences = 1)/lag(inputData$NSE50))
diff_RealM2<-(diff(inputData$RealMoney, lag = 1, differences = 1)/lag(inputData$RealMoney))


plot.ts(diff_NSE50)
#--------->
lm_fit = dynlm(IIP ~ CallMoneyRate + STCreditSpread + diff_NSE50 + diff_RealM2, data = inputData)
summary(lm_fit)
#--------->
inputData_ts = ts(inputData, frequency = 12, start = 2012)

#--------->area of my doubt is here 

VAR_data <- window(ts.union(ts(inputData$IIP), ts(inputData$CallMoneyRate)))
VAR_est <- VAR(y = VAR_data, p = 12)
plot(VAR_est)
```

I want to my plots to get plotted together in same plot. How do I serparate the var() plots to two separate ones.

Current plot:

[image: My current plot(source)]

My dataset :
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InZNS.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Try adding the result from dput(head(VAR_est)) to the question.

Comment: And which package is your VAR function from?

Comment: I have added my whole dataset.and VAR function is from vars package

Comment: Could you add the data in a form we can just copy and paste it in? Please use dput(), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more information

Comment: I did add dput(). Is that what you were trying to convey?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this still needs some work, but it should set the right framework for you. I would look more into working with the `ggplot2` for future.

Few extra packages needed, namely `library(vars)` and `library(dynlm)`.

Starting from,

```
VAR_est <- VAR(y = VAR_data, p = 12)
```

Now we extract the values we want from the `VAR_est` object.

```
y <- as.numeric(VAR_est$y[,1])
z <- as.numeric(VAR_est$y[,2])
x <- 1:length(y)


## second data set on a very different scale
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)  # Leave space for z axis
plot(x, y, type = "l") # first plot
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, z, type = "l", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side=4, at = pretty(range(z)))
mtext("z", side=4, line=3)
```

I will leave you to add the dotted lines on etc...

Hint: Decompose the `VAR_est` object, for example, `VAR_est$datamat`, then see which bit of data corresponds to the part of the plot you want.

Used some of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143251/9555388)

Comment: The plots look different and normal ts plots have been plotted.I think `VAR_est` did not standardize and scale the plots.Will ggplot2 help?

Comment: I see, one solution could be to standardise and scale the y and z data yourself? Assuming this is just subtracting the mean and dividing by the sd of the data? For example, `a <- c(1,2,3,4); std.a <- (a-mean(a)) / sd(a)`