# Two y Axes in RBokeh

Tags: r, bokeh, rbokeh

I need to draw a combo chart including two series of bars and two lines using RBokeh. The syntax for adding bars and lines is quite simple but I cannot add a second y-axis. `y_axis` position can be set to left or right but it does not work when I use them simultaneously.

```
p=figure(width = 600, height = 600) %>%
         ly_points(Data2Chart[c(4,1)], hover = dat) %>%
         ly_lines(Data2Chart[c(4,1)], legend = "X") %>%
         y_axis(position = 'right') %>% 
         y_axis(position = 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really think this is possible and actually also not quite advisible anyways even if it would be (see some discussion about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143251/8107362)). I would suggest doing two separate graphs and add them via `grid_plot()`.

A really hacky way would be to draw the second axis by yourself via `ly_abline(v=...)`. At least in my experience, rBokeh requires [a lot](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/rbokeh-tipps-and-tricks-with-javascript-and-beyond/) of [hackiness](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/rbokeh-dont-be-stopped-by-missing-arguments/)

Comment: RBokeh has not been updated in some time, but the folks who worked on it previously are hopefully preparing a big update to modern versions of BokehJS