# Barchart %smoking and %accidents across 50 states in US

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

newbie in R: wanted to to ask how I can plot two numerical variables (say smoking% and liquor consumption%) across 50 US states - I can easily do that in excel but still struggling in R; any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6snI4.jpg)

```
#Let's say here is my code:
smoking <- c(21, 23.4, 83)
drinking <- c(19.5, 28.9, 57)
States <- c(CA, NH, NJ)
```

How can i plot as barplot for smoking (red) and drinking (black) with states on x axis. Sorry Stacko won't allow me to upload pic or data file. Thanks again!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK1Ao.png)

Comment: Can you share some sample data or code? It would likely be possibly with ggplot.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales).

Comment: Is there a way to do this in R?  Yes... what kind of plot were you looking to create?  Bar chart, scatter chart, something combinig the two?... there are lots of options that will be avaialble, but what are you trying to convey with the plot?  Go from there, then think about what plot would best show that result, then finally when you know what you want - go for the coding.

Comment: Thanks Edward, KJM and chemdork. I wanted to create a barchart. I am adding the data and the excel snapshot in the original post above. I have used R for stats and plotting. And just can't fathom that R won't be able to do this.

Comment: this comes close: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybr4U.jpg But not quite there. I just need one Y axis scale since both my variable smoking and drinking are a percent. And the X axis is a categorical with names of states.

Comment: You should post some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: @william3031 I tried posting the code here - too long it says - don't get me wrong, however I am not asking you to help me based on your judgement after I justify I deserve so; Thanks anyway!!

Comment: It is more about actually showing that you have tried to solve the problem before asking for help, while also making it easier for others to help you with your question.  This might help you with the answer: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization and this might help you with getting an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @william3031 many thanks; this looks too complicated - it should not be so - I have used ggplot for my plots and statistical analysis using R; but this plot can be done in excel in 5 seconds - I can't give R more than 2 hours on this - doesn't seem a practical approach

Comment: It probably isn't complicated. But you're not providing the information that will help others help you with what you want to do despite many requests for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you provided, when it is put in a table, is not 'tidy'. You can read more about tidy data [here](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Here is what I have done to get your desired output, assuming you start with data like `df`:

```
smoking <- c(21, 23.4, 83)
drinking <- c(19.5, 28.9, 57)
States <- c("CA", "NH", "NJ")

# the 'messy' data
df <- data.frame("States" = States,
                 "Smoking" = smoking,
                 "Drinking" = drinking)
```

```
> df
  States Smoking Drinking
1     CA    21.0     19.5
2     NH    23.4     28.9
3     NJ    83.0     57.0
```

When can then use the `tidyr` package to transform it into long format. This is much easier to work with in `ggplot2`.

```
library(tidyr)
df_tidy <- pivot_longer(df, -States, names_to = "Type")
```

```
> df_tidy
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  States Type     value
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1 CA     Smoking   21  
2 CA     Drinking  19.5
3 NH     Smoking   23.4
4 NH     Drinking  28.9
5 NJ     Smoking   83  
6 NJ     Drinking  57
```

Finally, we can plot this using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = States, y = value)) +
        geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

We can also just use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`, which uses `stat = "identity"` by default, as we find out from [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) `tidyverse` help page.

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = States, y = value)) +
        geom_col(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge")
```

In either case, we get:

[image]

Comment: I am still studying tibble and df conversion - i did that long time ago in roger peng's data analysis (JHopkins) class when i had no grey hair :-)

Comment: is there a way to plot this as a 3D on a map of that state? I am actually intending to plot a 3d bar/elevator plot on a map of States in India. Any ideas? @stefan?

Comment: I want to appreciate the help provided by all above users in this thread and the stackoverflow community for your assistance in visualization of data in one of my upcoming publications. Kindly contact me if you do not consent to using your user ID in the acknowledgements. Thank you and all the best! Stay safe and healthy!!