# Rscript in PowerBI for combined boxplot with bar chart (separate y-axis)

Tags: r, powerbi, boxplot, powerbi-desktop

Total noob to both Stackoverflow and R so please be gentle!

I'm trying to create a single graph in PowerBI using R that combines a boxplot with a barchart on a time-series x-axis.  Something that looks like this:
[Boxplot w Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPMC.png) (also below).
[image: Boxplot with Barchart]

What I'm trying to achieve is an x-axis that is the week number (Weeknum) and y-axis for the barchart that is the count of 'LDS' and secondary y-axis that is a cost-per-mile range for 'CAD_CPM.'

I am able to create the boxplot using the below code but cannot seem to figure out how to add in the bar chart.

Any and all help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
boxplot (
CAD_CPM~Weeknum
,data=dataset
,main="Cost Per Mile (CAD)"
,outline = FALSE 
,ylab = "CPM (CAD)"
,xlab = ""
,col=(c("pink" , "light blue"))
    )
```

[PowerBI boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSIHD.png) (also below)

[image: PowerBI boxplot]

Comment: I don't know much about plotting in base R, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you've not provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), I have used the mtcars dataset in R to illustrate my point.
Try the following code in R script editor of PowerBI

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

temp <- data %>% 
  group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(data = temp, aes(cyl, mpg), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_light()
```

Will result in a boxplot combined with barplot as given below
[image: box-and-barplot-combined]

Now, suppose you want to add some spice to this plot, i.e., make a colorful plot, then try the following code;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

temp <- data %>% 
  group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
str(temp)

ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(data = temp, aes(cyl, mpg), stat = "identity",
           fill=temp$cyl) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(gear)))+
  theme_light()
```

Will result in following plot;

[image: box-bar-combined-colored]

**Adding a secondary y-axis** can be achieved by using the `sec_axis()` function. See the [official docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) for more info.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

temp <- data %>% 
  group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
str(temp)

ggplot(data, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(data = temp, aes(cyl, mpg), stat = "identity",
           fill=temp$cyl) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(gear)))+
  scale_y_continuous("mpg (US)",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1.20, name = "mpg (UK)"))+
  theme_light()
```

[image: secondary-y-axis]

Comment: Suppose I wanted the boxplot on a secondary Y-axis - how would I achieve that? Thanks!