# How to calculate fuzzy performance index and normalized classification entropy in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, fuzzy-c-means

I am running Fuzzy C-Means Clustering using `e1071` package. I want to decide the optimum number of clusters based on fuzzy performance index (FPI) (extent of fuzziness) and normalized classification entropy (NCE) (degree of disorganization of specific class) given in the following formula

[image]

where c is the number of clusters and n is the number of observations, μ<sub>ik</sub> is the fuzzy membership and log<sub>a</sub> is the natural logarithm.

I am using the following code

```
library(e1071)
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.3),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.3),ncol=2))
cl <- cmeans(x,2,20,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans")
cl$membership
```

I have been able to extract the μ<sub>ik</sub> i.e. fuzzy membership. Now, `cmeans` has to for different number of clusters e.g. 2 to 6 and the FPI and NCE has to be calculated to have a plot like the following

[image]

How can it be achieved in R?

**Edit**

I have tried the code provided by @nya for `iris` dataset using the following code

```
df <- scale(iris[-5])

FPI <- function(cmem){
  c <- ncol(cmem)
  n <- nrow(cmem)
  
  1 - (c / (c - 1)) * (1 - sum(cmem^2) / n)
}

NCE <- function(cmem){
  c <- ncol(cmem)
  n <- nrow(cmem)
  
  (n / (n - c)) * (- sum(cmem * log(cmem)) / n)
}

# prepare variables
cl <- list()
fpi <- nce <- NULL

# cycle through the desired number of clusters
for(i in 2:6){
  cl[[i]] <- cmeans(df, i, 20, method = "cmeans")
  fpi <- c(fpi, FPI(cl[[i]]$membership))
  nce <- c(nce, NCE(cl[[i]]$membership))
}

# add space for the second axis label
par(mar = c(5,4,1,4) + .1)

# plot FPI
plot(2:6, fpi, lty = 2, pch = 18, type = "b", xlab = "Number of clusters", ylab = "FPI")

# plot NCE, manually adding the second axis
par(new = TRUE)
plot(2:6, nce, lty = 1, pch = 15, type = "b", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
axis(4, at = pretty(range(nce)))
mtext("NCE", side = 4, line = 3)

# add legend
legend("top", legend = c("FPI", "NCE"), pch = c(18,15), lty = c(2,1), horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

The minimum values of fuzzy performance index(FPI) and normalized classification entropy (NCE) were considered to decide the optimum number of clusters. NCE is always increasing and FPI is showing the decreasing value. Ideally it should have been

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With available equations, we can program our own functions. Here, the two functions use equations present in the paper you suggested and one of the references the authors cite.

```
FPI <- function(cmem, method = c("FuzME", "McBrathney", "Rahul")){
    method = match.arg(method)
    C <- ncol(cmem)
    N <- nrow(cmem)

    # Rahul et al. 2019. https://doi.org/10.1080/03650340.2019.1578345
    if(method == "Rahul"){
        res <- 1 - (C / (C - 1)) * (1 - sum(cmem^2) / N)
    }
    # McBrathney & Moore 1985 https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-1923(85)90082-6
    if(method == "McBrathney"){
        F <- sum(cmem^2) / N
        res <- 1 - (C * F - 1) / (F - 1)
    }
    # FuzME https://precision-agriculture.sydney.edu.au/resources/software/
    # MATLAB code file fvalidity.m, downloaded on 11 Nov, 2021 
    if(method == "FuzME"){
        F <- sum(cmem^2) / N
        res <- 1 - (C * F - 1) / (C - 1)
    }
    return(res)
}

NCE <- function(cmem, method = c("FuzME", "McBrathney", "Rahul")){
    method = match.arg(method)
    C <- ncol(cmem)
    N <- nrow(cmem)

    if(method == "Rahul"){
        res <- (N / (N - C)) * (- sum(cmem * log(cmem)) / N)
    }
    if(method %in% c("FuzME", "McBrathney")){
        H <- -1 / N * sum(cmem * log(cmem)) 
        res <- H / log(C)
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Then use those to calculate the indices from the degrees of membership from the `cmeans` function from the `iris` dataset.

```
# prepare variables
cl <- list()
fpi <- nce <- NULL

# cycle through the desired number of clusters
for(i in 2:6){
    cl[[i]] <- e1071::cmeans(iris[, -5], i, 20, method = "cmeans")
    fpi <- c(fpi, FPI(cl[[i]]$membership, method = "M"))
    nce <- c(nce, NCE(cl[[i]]$membership, method = "M"))
}
```

Last, plot with [two different axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143251/5967807) in one plot.

```
# add space for the second axis label
par(mar = c(5,4,1,4) + .1)

# plot FPI
plot(2:6, fpi, lty = 2, pch = 18, type = "b", xlab = "Number of clusters", ylab = "FPI")

# plot NCE, manually adding the second axis
par(new = TRUE)
plot(2:6, nce, lty = 1, pch = 15, type = "b", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
axis(4, at = pretty(range(nce)))
mtext("NCE", side = 4, line = 3)

# add legend
legend("top", legend = c("FPI", "NCE"), pch = c(18,15), lty = c(2,1), horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

**EDIT1:** Updated the functions according to optional equations from two different publications and calculated the example on the `iris` dataset.

**EDIT2:** Added code for the FPI and NCE calculations specified in the FuzME MATLAB code available [here](https://precision-agriculture.sydney.edu.au/resources/software/).

Comment: I have tested your code with `iris` dataset. The minimum values of fuzzy performance index(FPI) and normalized classification entropy (NCE) were considered to decide the optimum number of clusters. NCE is always increasing and FPI is showing the decreasing value. I have updated my question. Can you please see to it?

Comment: @BappaDas Can you check that the functions `FPI` and `NCE` are implemented correctly? Specifically, the `c` and `n` arguments should be the number of clusters and the number of observations. Do those numbers correspond to the dimensions of `cl$membership`? I.e. for the `iris` dataset `n = 150` and is 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: Alternatively, what is the code for producing the values in the reference image in your question?

Comment: I have not coded it. I have taken it from [this](https://krishi.icar.gov.in/jspui/bitstream/123456789/31927/1/Assessing%20soil_R%20Tripathi.pdf) manuscript.

Comment: The equations differ from publication to publication (I checked the two specified in the edited answer). The answer now shows the alternative from McBrathney & Moore 1985. However, the software they use (FuzMe) implements both indices differently, not matching any of the publications. Do you want the FuzMe option as well?

Comment: Actually I am not able to use FuzMe software in windows 10 software. If you can show FuzMe option as well, it will be great.

Comment: @BappaDas The FuzME methods are now included in the code. However, note that the McBrathney & Moore paper and the MATLAB code of FuzME use the same equation for the NCE calculation. If my answer helped with your problem, please award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(cl) {
  C <- length(cl$size)
  N <- sum(cl$size)
  mu <- cl$membership
  fpi <- 1 - C / (C - 1) * (1 - sum((mu)^2) / N)
  nce <- N / (N - C) * (-sum(log(mu) * mu) / N)
  c(FPI = fpi, NCE = nce)
}

data.frame(t(rbind(
  K = 2:6,
  sapply(
    K,
    function(k) f(cmeans(x, k, 20, verbose = TRUE, method = "cmeans"))
  )
))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = FPI:NCE, names_to = "Index") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = K, y = value, group = Index)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Index, color = Index)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "FPI",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "NCE")
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]